# Oracle Text query with CONTAINS operator and wildcard on stopword does not find results

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

Why does the Oracle Text `CONTAINS` query operator not return any results when a wildcard is applied on a stopword?

Example:
(Those sample values assume that an english stoplist is used - that depends on the DB language. If you use a different DB language, just replace "are" and "there" with stopwords from your language.)

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SEARCHTEST (VALUE VARCHAR2(200 CHAR));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE INDEX IX_SEARCHTEST ON SEARCHTEST(VALUE)
  2    INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
  3    PARAMETERS('SYNC (ON COMMIT)');

Index created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO SEARCHTEST VALUES ('searchtest');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO SEARCHTEST VALUES ('searchtest test');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO SEARCHTEST VALUES ('searchtest are');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO SEARCHTEST VALUES ('searchtest there');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest
searchtest test
searchtest are
searchtest there

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest test') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest test

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest are') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest
searchtest test
searchtest are
searchtest there

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest there') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest
searchtest test
searchtest are
searchtest there

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest%') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest
searchtest test
searchtest are
searchtest there

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest test%') > 0;

VALUE
------------------------------
searchtest test

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest are%') > 0;

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM SEARCHTEST WHERE CONTAINS(VALUE, 'searchtest there%') > 0;

no rows selected
```

As you can see, the last 2 queries do not return the expected result. Why is that, and how can it be fixed?
Note: I can't just remove the wildcard from the query, since it is automatically appended to the search text that was entered by the user to enable prefix searches.

DB Version:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.12.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This is by design according to Oracle:

> This is a bit of subtle one. First I would recommend reading
> “Understanding Stopword Transformations” in the doc (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/astoptrn.htm#CCREF1900)
>
> If you look at H.2 for phrase queries, a stopword is transformed into
> “no_token”. So “searchtest are” is the same as just “searchtest” and
> you get a match on all of the documents in the example.
>
> However, as soon as you stick a wildcard at the end: ‘searchtest are%’
> then ‘are%’ is no longer a stopword. We are looking for words like
> ‘area’ or ‘arena’ which are not stopwords. So we do an actual phrase
> query, looking for the word ‘searchtest’ followed by another word
> starting with ‘are’. Text has no way to know that searchtest was
> followed by the stopword ‘are’ (because that information is not stored
> anywhere) so we don’t get a match.
>
> It is arguable that we should detect that the expansion matches a
> stopword and effectively remove it. However this could result in
> undesirable behavior for other searches. Do we really want a search
> for ‘suc%’ to fail (no hits) just because ‘suc%’ matches the stopword
> ‘such’ ?